# Implementing Telerik combobox but it's rendering simple textbox with no list

Tags: razor, telerik-mvc

Following is the code i am trying to hook with Telerik Combobox but it aint working

```
 @(Html.Telerik().ComboBox().Name("ComboBox").BindTo(ViewBag.GenreId))
```

GenreId is a select list passed in the viewbag. Following is the controller code

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name");
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see a problem with your Code there. Have you checked the select list is actually populated? Also have you checked that all your Telerik libraries are added? Try creating a combo with a known selectlist that you created in code.